# I'm having problems creating a sed script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

My teacher didn't really go over sed scripts so they're very confusing. I need to finish this to get an A though. It's due very soon so I doubt I have time to fully understand it because I don't understand the syntax at all.

The instructions are:
Create a sed script named script3 that will print a file with “The Raven” at the top, replace every occurrence of multiple spaces with a single space, and print a line of 30 dashes below each line.

This is what I have so far:

#### sed script

```
echo "The Raven"
s/[ ]\{2,\}/ /g
/\,\./ s/^/------------------------------ /
```

Comment: SO normally doesn't do homework, tests, assignments, exams,...

Comment: do you have file on which you should perform all above?

Answer (score 3):

Using the online [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

- use the [`i` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) with an address to insert the title
- use the [`a` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) with no address to append  the separator after every line
- use `s/[[:blank:]]\+/ /g` to replace any horizontal whitespace characters with a single space: [sed regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html#ed-regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`*Create a sed script named script3*

so create a text file calles script3 taht is called with `sed -f script3 YourSoureFile`
content is

```
1 i\
The raven
s/ \{2,\}/ /g
a\
------------------------------
```

*that will print a file with*

*“The Raven” at the top*

```
1 i\
The raven
```

on 1st (1) line, insert (i) the next line (each line following until last cahr is NO NORE `\`

*replace every occurrence of multiple spaces with a single space*

```
s/ \{2,\}/ /g
```

substitute (s///) any pattern (part of text between the separator `/`composed of 2 or more `\{2,\}` following space  jsute before the occurance specification, by a singel space the second , any occurence present ( option g). This happend at each line (no number or filter pattern in the head of the line like the `1` on precedent line)

*and print a line of 30 dashes below each line*

```
a\
------------------------------
```

(a) work like the (i) but append in this case. No filter pattern nor number indicate line to act, so on each line also.

i and a add text to ouptut but not on working buffer, so this cannot be manipulate inside this sed action, this is not the case of s/// that work ON the current working buffer (that is print at end of treatment of the line, before starting with a new line)
This is what I have so far:

**About your script**

```
echo "The Raven"
```

that is not a sed action but a shell action so, it cannot work in a sed like this (could using shell substitution but not the goal normaly)

```
s/[ ]\{2,\}/ /g
```

it's fine, class `[]` for this space is not necessary here but litterally ok. You could use `[[:space:]]` or `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:][:blank:]]` to be exhaustif using meta class of type `[:xxxxx:]` inside a class

```
/\,\./ s/^/------------------------------ /
```

this will mean *on each occurence of `,.` (both and in this order), replace (add thus) the start of the line with 30 `-` and a space. So it's not occuring on each line and it add at the start not following the line. A way using s/// could be:

```
s/.*/&\
------------------------------/
```

Replace on each line every char (all at once) by herself (&) followed by a new line and 30 dash